# Laravel 5.4 pusher error

Tags: php, node.js, laravel, vue.js, pusher

I am using pusher in Laravel 5.4 but I'm getting following error:

> WebSocket connection to 'ws://ws.pusherapp.com/app/731e32c5f123456298e?protocol=7&client=js&version=4.1.0&flash=false' failed: WebSocket is closed before the connection is established.
>
> Pusher : Error : {"type":"WebSocketError","error":{"type":"PusherError","data":{"code":4001,"message":"Did you forget to specify the cluster when creating the Pusher instance?  App key 731e32c5f123456298e does not exist in this cluster."}}}

Comment: Did you forget to specify the cluster when creating the Pusher instance?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you've copied your pusher `app_key` incorrectly. Pusher app keys typically have 20 characters, yours has 19.

Comment: Sorry app key is ok, I have changed the key in error.

Comment: Which cluster is your app located in? eg: `mt1`/`eu`/`ap1`

Answer (score 1):

```
'pusher' => [
        'driver'      => 'pusher',
        'key'           => env('PUSHER_KEY'),
        'secret'     => env('PUSHER_SECRET'),
        'app_id'     => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
        'options'   => [
            'cluster'        =>   <your cluster>  ,
            'encrypted' => true,
        ],
    ],
```

Specify your cluster

however if you are testing on localhost encrypted should be false

Comment: however if you are testing on localhost encrypted should be false

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue and fixed it by adding cluster in Pusher function call of javascript:

```
var pusher = new Pusher('PUSHER_APP_KEY', {
    cluster: 'PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER'
    encrypted: true
});
```