# I am using pusher in Laravel 5.4 but I'm getting following error:

Tags: javascript, node.js, laravel, pusher

app.js echo script:

```
Echo:join('chatroom')


.listen('MessagePosted', (e) => {
                this.messages.push({
                    message: e.message.message,
                    user: e.user
                });
            });
```

getting following error:

> app.js:37859 [Vue warn]: Error in created hook: "ReferenceError: join
>   is not defined"
>
> (found in )warn @ app.js:37859handleError @ app.js:37944callHook
>   @ app.js:39983Vue._init @ app.js:41425Vue$3 @ app.js:41520(anonymous
>   function) @ app.js:1127__webpack_require__ @ app.js:20(anonymous
>   function) @ app.js:47150__webpack_require__ @ app.js:20(anonymous
>   function) @ app.js:66(anonymous function) @ app.js:69 app.js:37948
>   ReferenceError: join is not defined(…)handleError @
>   app.js:37948callHook @ app.js:39983Vue._init @ app.js:41425Vue$3 @
>   app.js:41520(anonymous function) @ app.js:1127__webpack_require__ @
>   app.js:20(anonymous function) @ app.js:47150__webpack_require__ @
>   app.js:20(anonymous function) @ app.js:66(anonymous function) @
>   app.js:69 app.js:45006 Download the Vue Devtools extension for a
>   better development experience:

Comment: The `:` in `Echo:join` looks invalid. Did you mean `Echo.join`? `join` is a method of the `Echo` object, according to the Laravel documentation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel 5.4 pusher error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44960405/laravel-5-4-pusher-error)

Answer (score 0):

install `pusher` and `laravel-echo`

you can install it by using

```
npm install --save laravel-echo pusher-js
```

I hope this helps

you will also need to compile the code